# How to create an Entity Listener lazily and inject dependencies into it

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, entitylisteners

Before Doctrine 2.4 the default way to catch lifecycle events (like `prePersist`) was a global **[event listener](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/events.html#implementing-event-listeners)** that would fire for ALL entities. Running such a listener as a Symfony service made it easy to inject other services (like the `request` or `request_stack` objects).

Now the better solution seems to be an **[entity listener](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/events.html#entity-listeners)** since that comes with much less overhead!

So let's start this thing up in our entities header...:

```
* @ORM\EntityListeners({ "AppBundle\Entity\Listener\LanguageListener" })
```

And here's the class:

```
namespace AppBundle\Entity\Listener;

use Doctrine\ORM\Event\LifecycleEventArgs;

class LanguageListener
{
    public function prePersist($obj_entity, LifecycleEventArgs $obj_eventArgs)
    {    
        $request = ???;

        // set entity to users preferred language (for example 'de')
        $obj_entity->setLanguage($request->getLocale());
    }
}
```

As you can see, I have not the slightest idea how to access Symfonys services (in this case the `request` object).

But wait! There is a way:

```
global $kernel;
if ('AppCache' == get_class($kernel))
{
    $kernel = $kernel->getKernel();
}
$request = $kernel->getContainer()->get('request');
```

And it's working too.

But in all my research I found a lot of related questions strictly warning about excactly that!
Only difference: all those questions were referring to **Entities**, not to **Entity listeners**...

... leading me to these two questions:

1. Is the above solution the way to go?
2. And if not: how should it be done?

---

**[Edit:]** Once again (see first sentence) let me make clear that this question is also about how to **not** use a service. Services come at some cost, see [Expensive Service Construction](https://tideways.io/profiler/blog/5-ways-to-optimize-symfony-baseline-performance). And particularly in this case I rarely need the functionality - that's why I want to go with Entity Listeners that do **not** run as service.

Sorry I didn't over emphasize this side aspect. Not sure why this qualified for a rate down though...

**[Edit2:]** To make things clearer I added one more code example (the first one) that shows how the thing is mapped.

Comment: have you already see [Entity listeners resolver](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/events.html#entity-listeners-resolver)?

Comment: I think this the solution in conjunction with the symfony way [Entity Listeners](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/DoctrineBundle/entity-listeners.html)

Comment: Might be, I didn't really grasp the resolver concept yet. Read about it earlier today though, good read:
[Entity Listener Resolver](http://egeloen.fr/2013/12/01/symfony2-doctrine2-entity-listener-as-serice/)

But anyway this still wouldn't solve my problem.

Comment: As far as I know it's considered bad practice to have services which accept a container as an argument. You should rather pass the service you need instead. @Matteo's approach is what Eddie should do to get things working.

Answer (score 9):

As of `doctrine/doctrine-bundle >= 1.5.0` entity listeners can be created as services and if they are tagged with `doctrine.orm.entity_listener` they will be registered into [the desired entity manager](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/DoctrineBundle/entity-listeners.html) automatically. You can inject the required dependencies into the service e.g. the request stack.

Create a listener:

```
namespace AppBundle\Doctrine\Listener;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RequestStack;

class LanguageListener
{
    /**
     * @var RequestStack
     */
    private $requestStack;

    public function __construct(RequestStack $requestStack)
    {
        $this->requestStack = $requestStack;
    }

    public function prePersist($entity)
    {
        if (null !== $request = $this->requestStack->getCurrentRequest()) {
            // put the logic here
        }
    }
}
```

Register it as a service:

```
app.doctrine.language_listener:
    class: AppBundle\Doctrine\Listener\LanguageListener
    public: false
    arguments: ["@request_stack"]
    tags:
        - { name: "doctrine.orm.entity_listener" }
```

Annotate entities:

```
namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use FOS\UserBundle\Entity\User as BaseUser;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity()
 * @ORM\EntityListeners("AppBundle\Doctrine\Listener\LanguageListener")
 * @ORM\Table("user_")
 */
class User extends BaseUser
{
    // ...  
}
```

**Note** that entity listener registered this way are not lazily loaded, so they and their dependencies will be created when the entity manager is created.

**UPDATE:**

So if your question is about how to use it lazily. The first solution that comes in my mind to declare it as a [lazy service](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dependency_injection/lazy_services.html), but in this case it actually does not work as expected because in the annotation we use a concrate class which will be created by the listener resolver when needed, but in this case we should write the proxy class name in the annotation, to use the proxy object instead, which is not possible. There is a solution though  (which is not documented at the moment), **do not annotate** the entity with `@EntityListeners`, but use tag parameters to register the listener. Something like this:

```
app.doctrine.language_listener:
    class: AppBundle\Doctrine\Listener\LanguageListener
    arguments: ["@request_stack"]
    lazy: true
    tags:
        - { name: "doctrine.orm.entity_listener", entity: AppBundle\Entity\User, event: preUpdate }
        - { name: "doctrine.orm.entity_listener", entity: AppBundle\Entity\User, event: postUpdate }
```

This way you can use lazy services, but it only works with `doctrine/orm >= 2.5.0`.

An another solution would be to [create an own entity listener resolver](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/events.html#entity-listeners-resolver) which knows about the container (this is actually not a good thing) and uses it to get the listener when it is needed. There is a [blog post](http://egeloen.fr/2013/12/01/symfony2-doctrine2-entity-listener-as-serice/) about a way to do it.

Comment: Thank you for your concise answer! But it's not an answer to my problem:
I am well aware that I could use a service and inject everything (also how it's done). But that's excactly what I am trying to avoid. See the new edit **and** my first sentence in the original question.

Comment: Then I don't really get what do you wan to achieve here. This is an entity listener listening on events of the User entity. This is how it should be done. If you wan't to instantiate it manually you have to do the same thing what the container does now. You have to register it into the entity manager ASAP to catch the events you need. You can try and define it as a [lazy service](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dependency_injection/lazy_services.html) so a proxy will be created instead (but that requires 'symfony/proxy-manager-bridge') or create a factory.

Comment: Well, I see that my above solution is working: and it's only loaded and called when needed. And since it's the Doctrine way it can't be totally wrong, right? The only problem is how to access the `request` service in the proper way.

Comment: Thanx for the lazy service link, I didn't know that. Sounds promising!

Comment: "Well, I see that my above solution is working: and it's only loaded and called when needed"... that is not true... how you register the listener into the EM? You have to do that on every request. BTW you should keep in mind that this approach only works in the web context and don't in e.g. console commands as there is no request there.

Comment: "how you register the listener into the EM? You have to do that on every request." That's not true. This is the annotation line you need to register the listener to only one entity:  `@ORM\EntityListeners({ "AppBundle\Entity\Listener\LanguageListener" })`
This listener will only come to live (__construct) when the concerned entity is used.

Comment: That's the first line in my [2nd link](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/events.html#entity-listeners). Basically that's the call, just like `$obj->doSomething()` would be. I didn't state that in my question because it's obvious and doesn't contribute to the problem in focus. Still don't get, why someone would vote me down for "no research effort, unclear or not useful". Grrr.

Comment: Yes, you are right and now I know what was your question really about. According to these it was not clear for me (and apparently for others too). I updated my answer with a solution for the real problem.